# How does one transfer files to S3 from heroku rails 3 AWS v1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my rails 3 app I'm generating a file when a user does an action. This file needs to be permanent. So this file needs to be stored in some place like S3 AWS. What is the simplest way to do this using S3 AWS (aws-sdk v1)?

The image its genererated using the gem barby (https://github.com/toretore/barby), so the user doesn't need to upload it.

Comment: Your questions a bit broad. How is this file being generated? Is it a user upload? I'd recommend checking out the Fog gem https://github.com/fog/fog with the AWS adapter.

Comment: Thank for your reply Anthony. The image its  generated using the gem barby https://github.com/toretore/barby  The user does NOT upload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AWS SDK for Ruby to copy the file to S3. The [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html) pretty much gives you the code:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/path/to/source/file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Mark B! This is with the version AWS SDK version 2. 
Witht the version 1 its:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
s3 = AWS::S3.new
# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => file_name)
```

Comment: Why would you use an old version of the SDK?

Comment: Compatibility issues. I'm working with paperclip paperclip 4.2.0